# Including a baseline risk for each participant to consider having a different number of data points in Cox model

Tags: survival, cox-model

We used the Cox model to associate environmental exposures with time to heart failure using cohort data.

The following question has been raised:

*When using the extended Cox model, did you include a baseline risk for each participant to consider having a different number of data points for each individual?*

Any idea of how to consider the different number of data points in the baseline hazard? Any references that you may know of is appreciated.

Comment: Do you have repeated measures for subjects? Perhaps the reviewer is referring to time dependent covariates?